# How to show Zoom In - Zoom Out Image Animation

Tags: android, animation, gif, animated-gif, zooming

What is the best way of `showing` **Zoom In** and **Zoom Out** `Images`

Either by using `.gif` image or `zoom in/out` animation ?

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Comment: Have you [tried this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)

Comment: @NadeemIqbal yes but i don't want touch zoom, i am looking for automatic zoom in zoom out image example like zoom in for 5 seconds and then zoom out for 5 seconds....and so on

Comment: You only want to zoom in for X seconds and then zoom out after Y seconds??? Do you have only one image and ImageView???

Comment: @NadeemIqbal yes i posted my ImageView xml code, and please share your code if you have ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    To make image zoom in or zoom out you need to use custom class 
    Here is custom class which i use is named as **TouchImageView.java**
    and here is code
    *******************
    public class TouchImageView extends ImageView 
    {

        Matrix matrix;

        // We can be in one of these 3 states
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int DRAG = 1;
        static final int ZOOM = 2;
        int mode = NONE;

        // Remember some things for zooming
        PointF last = new PointF();
        PointF start = new PointF();
        float minScale = 1f;
        float maxScale = 3f;
        float[] m;


        int viewWidth, viewHeight;
        static final int CLICK = 3;
        float saveScale = 1f;
        protected float origWidth, origHeight;
        int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;


        ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

        Context context;

        public TouchImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            sharedConstructing(context);
        }

        public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            sharedConstructing(context);
        }

        private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
            super.setClickable(true);
            this.context = context;
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
            matrix = new Matrix();
            m = new float[9];
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

            setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            last.set(curr);
                            start.set(last);
                            mode = DRAG;
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            if (mode == DRAG) {
                                float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                                float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                                float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                                float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                                matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                                fixTrans();
                                last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                            }
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            mode = NONE;
                            int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                            int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                            if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                                performClick();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            mode = NONE;
                            break;
                    }

                    setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    invalidate();
                    return true; // indicate event was handled
                }

            });
        }

        public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
            maxScale = x;
        }

        private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                mode = ZOOM;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
                float origScale = saveScale;
                saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
                if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                    saveScale = maxScale;
                    mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
                } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                    saveScale = minScale;
                    mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
                }

                if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
                else
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

                fixTrans();
                return true;
            }
        }

        void fixTrans() {
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

            float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
            float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

            if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
                matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
        }

        float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
            float minTrans, maxTrans;

            if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
                minTrans = 0;
                maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            } else {
                minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
                maxTrans = 0;
            }

            if (trans < minTrans)
                return -trans + minTrans;
            if (trans > maxTrans)
                return -trans + maxTrans;
            return 0;
        }

        float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
            if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
                return 0;
            }
            return delta;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            //
            // Rescales image on rotation
            //
            if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                    || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
                return;
            oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
            oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

            if (saveScale == 1) {
                //Fit to screen.
                float scale;

                Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
                if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                    return;
                int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

                Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

                float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
                float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
                scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
                matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

                // Center the image
                float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
                float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
                redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
                redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

                matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

                origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
                origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
            fixTrans();
        }
    }
    ********************
    now set image view root class as TouchImageView here my package name is com.qd so
    <com.qd.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
   ============================================



    Now my next class is named as 
    ImagePagerActivity which contains 
    reference of com.qd.TouchImageView
    here it is code as below

 **ImagePagerActivity.java file** code below here


public class ImagePagerActivity extends Activity
{
     TouchImageView imageview;
     RelativeLayout relative;
     Bitmap bmp;
     Bitmap bMapRotate;
     int r;
     View test_view;
     MotionEvent me;
     LayoutParams mParams;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imagepager);
        imageview = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        final Button back_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnback);
        relative = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.progressView);
        new MyTask().execute();

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                }
            });  



     }




     class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
     {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                relative.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
            {
                try
                {
                    //rotate(test_view, me);
                    String urlstr = getIntent().getExtras().getString("image_id");
                    URL url = new URL(urlstr);
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                } 
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                relative.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                imageview.setMaxZoom(4f);
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
    }
}
```